# My iOS simulator is rendering with glitches

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have a 2019 16-inch Macbook Pro with an i7. My iOS simulator is showing terrible behavior on Xcode 12 and 13. The rendering happens only partially. I start typing but only top part of the TextField updates. When I pull my modally presented controllers up and down, it leaves glitches and artifacts in the render whenever I release the mouse pointer from the window. Only when I drag and click something in the simulator, only then the screen updates properly.

I have tried resetting the simulator and the machine, and different versions of Xcode AND or simulator iOS and nothing helps. I also have not found too specific mentions of this issue online.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that was fixed in Xcode 13. It primarily affects the iPhone mini so you can workaround it by using a different simulator.

Comment: iPhone mini? lmao I never used any other simulator other than iPhone mini lol